# Angular 10 Reactive Form - Limit number of chars in user input field

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm building an Angular 10 reactive form and want to limit the number of chars the user can enter into an input field. The maxLength Validator doesn't prevent the user from entering more chars - the form only becomes invalid. No more chars should appear in the input field if the user has reached the limit of chars. I'm using the form builder:

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]],
});


<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" required />
  </label>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: You could bind to [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) `maxLength` property.

Comment: Use the native `maxLength="10"` on the input itself. That being said, UX is better if you allow typing more and show a descriptive error.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you write a directive that prevents key down.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appMaxLength]"
})
export class MaxLengthDirective {
  @Input() appMaxLength;
  el:any;
  constructor(el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  @HostListener("paste", ["$event"]) onPaste(event){
   setTimeout(()=>{
    const value = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const maxLength = parseInt(this.appMaxLength);
    if (value.length > maxLength -1) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = value.substring(0, (maxLength));
    }
   })
    
  }

  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"]) onKeydown(event) {
    const value = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const maxLength = parseInt(this.appMaxLength);
    const keycode = event.which || event.keycode;
    const allowedKeycodes = [8,13,46, 37,38,39,40]
    const keyCodeIndex = allowedKeycodes.indexOf(keycode);
    if(keyCodeIndex != -1){
      return;
    }
    if (value.length > maxLength -1) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

To get the List of keycodes: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-34djqh

Working example with Keycode Index: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgsrx5

Working example with Paste functionality: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xeei1m

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. (We should allow the backspace and arrow keys.)

Comment: This would still allow someone to paste text over the limit.

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling I just tested the working example, and it is not allowing more than 10 characters. Let me know your test case.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene copy and paste using mouse click, not the keyboard.

Comment: @LarryFlewwelling Thanks for pointing. Added an update for paste functionality too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the maxlength HTML attribute to limit the number of chars in your text input.

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" maxlength="10" required />
  </label>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```